# How to make Xcode debug build be exactly like ad hoc build?

Tags: ios, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm having a nightmare bug that only happens on ad hoc build, doesn't create a crash log when it happens and is proving impossible to track down. I laboriously added alertviews everywhere until I found the statement where it is supposedly happening (shows alert view before but not after this statement). So I comment that statement out and it's STILL happening somewhere. I've been at this for 8 hours now and I really just need to get this effing bug to happen in a debugging session. How can I create the exact conditions of ad hoc build (optimizations or whatever) in a debug build so I can track this down?